# How to ignore route data in parameter binding

Tags: routes, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

Is there a way to instruct WebApi to ignore a route data value (a pattern in the route url) when binding the route values to a controller's action's parameters?

Example:

Having this route declaration

```
routes.Map("RouteName", "/api/{v}/{controller}/{action}/{id}");
```

I would like it to ignore the **{v}** pattern, as if it wasn't there, so for instance this url

```
"/api/123/Testing/Customer/24"
```

would map to the GetCustomer method below:

```
public class TestingController
{
   [HttpGet, ActionName("Customer")]
   public CustomerData GetCustomer(int id)
   {
     return ...
   } 
}
```

I don't want to add an **int v** parameter in GetCustomer method as I am not going to use it in any way. I just want it to be present in the url (no need to ask why, I just want to know if it is possible, either with a WebApi built in functionality or with a custom extension)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this functionality is included by default in WebApi. Specifically, all template parameters in the routeTemplate that do not have an equivalent parameter in the method's parameters, are ignored.

The example I gave in the question works out of the box. The **v** template parameter is ignored and the url is indeed mapped to the desired method.